# how can I animate drawing svg path in my swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, svg, swift3, uibezierpath

In my ios swift app I have `SVG` file - it's a shape of a map marker, now I want to draw it with animation. I managed to display the drawing thanks to the usage of `pocketSVG` https://github.com/pocketsvg/PocketSVG/ My code is as follows:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainLogoView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mainLogo", withExtension: "svg")!

    //initialise a view that parses and renders an SVG file in the bundle:
    let svgImageView = SVGImageView.init(contentsOf: url)

    //scale the resulting image to fit the frame of the view, but
    //maintain its aspect ratio:
    svgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    //layout the view:
    svgImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    mainLogoView.addSubview(svgImageView)

    svgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainLogoView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    svgImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainLogoView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    svgImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainLogoView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    svgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainLogoView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(2), target: self, selector: "functionHere", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}

func functionHere(){
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "MainSegue", sender: nil)
}
```

So basically in my ViewController I added on storyboard a `view` called `mainLogoView` and then I'm displaying there the SVG file. Now, since it's a shaped marker, very similar to this: http://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/116/116395.svg I want to draw it - during the time of 2 seconds I want to draw the shape around the circle.

How can I do it?

=====EDIT:

Following Josh's advice I commented out most of the code in my `viewDidLoad` and did instead:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mainLogo", withExtension: "svg")!

    for path in SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: url)
    {
        var layer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = path.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = 4
        layer.strokeColor = orangeColor.cgColor
        layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        mainLogoView.addSubview(layer)
    }
```

but now the last line throws an error

```
Cannot convert value of type 'CAShapeLayer' to expected argument type 'UIView'
```

Also, after editing my code - could you give me a hint how could I use Josh's method here?

Comment: A layer is not a UIView, but a UIView does have a layer property.  You need to add the shapeLayer to the layer as a sublayer.  mainLogoView.layer.addSublayer(layer).  Also the animation is not going to be right if you have multiple paths (you could do it if you chain them).  The intent is that you have a single path and all of the points in that path are in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to draw it finally :) I did it with: `for path in SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: url) { var layer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer() layer.frame = self.mainLogoView.layer.bounds` however seems like setting up the bounds didn't work well - the image is huuge. How can I fit it to the `mainLogoView`?

Comment: I'm adding it to the view with `mainLogoView.layer.insertSublayer(layer, at: 0)`

Comment: You should scale the SVG file to the correct size.  If you need a variable size you need to compute it in viewDidLayoutSubviews and scale it using the layer's .transform property.

Comment: Josh, could you be so kind and write a simple piece of code how could I do that? I don't know how it works and cannot find reliable tutorial for that :(

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the imageView method convert your SVG into a cgPath.  Assign this path to a CAShapeLayer and add that shape layer to your view.  You can animate the CAShapeLayer's endStroke as follows:

```
    func animateSVG(From startProportion: CGFloat, To endProportion: CGFloat, Duration duration: CFTimeInterval = animationDuration) {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.duration = duration
        animation.fromValue = startProportion
        animation.toValue = endProportion
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
        svgLayer.strokeEnd = endProportion
        svgLayer.strokeStart = startProportion
        svgLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateRing")
    }
```

Comment: hm, could you please provide a little bit more detailed code example? I'm not sure what are the `strokeEnd` and `animateRing` here, also I don't know how exactly could I convert my svg to cgPath :(

Comment: You should change the animateRing identifier, but anyways its totally arbitrary; its just the name of your animation.  strokeEnd is part of CAShapeLayer.  See the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer

Comment: hm, ok, and could you please show me some example of how do you exactly call this function in the code?

Comment: animateSVG(from: 0, to: 1, duration: 2) strokes the path from 0% to 100% of the path length  over two seconds.

Comment: could you please check the edit part of my original question?

Answer (score 0):

I did encounter the same problem, this is my solution. svgWidth, svgHeight are width and height of svg tag

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mainLogo", withExtension: "svg")!

for path in SVGBezierPath.pathsFromSVG(at: url)
{
    var layer:CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(CGFloat(mainLogoView.frame.width/svgWidth), CGFloat(mainLogoView.frame.height/svgHeight), 1)

    layer.path = path.cgPath
    layer.lineWidth = 4
    layer.strokeColor = orangeColor.cgColor
    layer.fillColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2, 2, 1)
    mainLogoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
}
```